# How to edit the amount of the non-recurring subtotal & total in php in woocommerce subscriptions?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, checkout

Using WooCommerce hooks, I want to edit only the non-recurring subtotal and total:

[[image: The things I want to edit]

For example, if there is a subscription product in cart, I want to edit only the one-shot payment without altering the recurring payment amount...

I tried several things, but I didn't succeed to have what I expected.

```
function adjust_price_2 ($cart) { 
    //var_dump($cart);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'adjust_price_2' );
```